# PHP: Using preg_match to trim characters proceeding '-'

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have an unserialized array, I'm attempting to modify a string in the array and remove characters proceeding and including the hyphen.

The string looks like this, it's length isn't always regular though 'SOMETEXT - 150 x 50'

I have attempted a regular expression but it does not work, this is my first attempt at creating a regular expression.

```
$item['options']['Size'] = preg_replace('/^[^-]*,\s*/', '', $item);
```

If anyone would mind pointing me in the right direction here that would be fantastic.

Comment: What is your desired output? your question is kinda unclear

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to remove all characters proceeding the hyphen in the string here: 'SOMETEXT - 150 x 50'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/-[^-]*$/', '', $item);
```

This should do it for you.

Comment: That's fantastic. This is going to be a fairly regular task for me, out of interest how would I configure that reg ex to remove everything preceding the hyphen? I'm trying to get my head around the syntax. Thanks

Comment: @LiamFell `^[^-]*` should do it

Comment: So the complete function would look like this? preg_replace('/^[^-]*$/', '', $item);

Comment: @LiamFell `preg_replace('/^[^-]*/', '', $item);` you dont need `$` der